# Cuyuna Lakes, MN Camping?

Tags: mountain-bike, advice

Has anyone rode the trails at Cuyuna Lakes in Ironton, Minnesota?

***Wondering if there is tent camping at the base of any of the trail systems*** that a guy can literally ride into camp at the bottom ?

If so, can you give me some advice? Where to go...best place to grab...heads up about anything... etc.

Thanks stackers!

Comment: perhaps try http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/ as well.

Comment: have you tried posting on TripAdvisor? Just strikes me that you might have more luck on a location-oriented site rather than somewhere that's primarily cycling-oriented

Comment: Call the chamber of commerce: (218) 546-8131

Comment: (That area of the state is filthy with resorts and campgrounds.  The Cuyuna County State Recreation Area has a campground, and there are maybe 2 dozen private campgrounds.  But most are not really set up for tent camping, so you probably need to ask someone in the area.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a quick search on Google, I was able to find [Portsmouth Campground](http://www.dnr.state.mn.us/state_parks/cuyuna_country/index.html), which looks to be pretty close to the trails. They also have yurts available, which might be nice as they aren't too expensive and you might even be able to fit your bike inside if you didn't have too many people.